# Focus the window in IE on click of the button if window is already openend.

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

Got Stuck up with this pretty problem!!!!
Suppose on click of a button we are opening a new window with the address "www.google.com".Now if we again click on that button new window should not be opened rather the already opened window with the address should gain the focus.

My approach towards the solution is as follows.

1)Firstly i tried to get the url's of all the opened tabs.

```
        SHDocVw.ShellWindows shellWindows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
        string filename;
        bool sdOpen = false;
        string[] openedTabs = new string[shellWindows.Count];
        int j = 0;
        foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows)
        {

            filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ie.FullName).ToLower();
            if (filename.Equals("iexplore"))
            {
                openedTabs[j] = ie.LocationURL.ToString();
                j++;
            }
```

2)Now i am struggling to have focus,if the tab is already openend.

Would appreciate immediate Help!Thanks..

Comment: *Would appreciate immediate Help* - yes, I'm sure you would, but putting that isn't going to make people rush to help you

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you're using C# code (something that happens on the server) trying to find information about an instance of IE (something that is running on the client)

Comment: So please suggest a solution that can be made on client side since you might  have understood the scenario well..